# PSQL: "ERROR: type "public.ip4" does not exist" at import from .sql file

Tags: import, psql

I import a .sql file that has been dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.3. I have psql version 10.15. I get the type error from the title of this post. I read the first lines of the .sql file and no type is being defined. Is public.ip4 an inbuilt type? Is the error due to the different versions? What does the point in the name mean, that it is a "subtype" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there is no type called `ip4` in the schema `public`.

The cause is probably that you are using a very old (minor) version of PostgreSQL to create the dump. There have been several bug fixes since that concern `search_path` problems.

You should dump the database with `pg_dump` from version 10.15.

Comment: I cannot change the dump, since I got it from someone else. But he mentioned that the schema that is being exported does not lie in the search path. What do you mean with "fixes that concern search_path problems"?

Comment: Then the problem is trivial. You exported only a certain schema, but the objects in that schema are using a data type from a schema that is not being exported. Of course restore has to fail. I was assuming that it had to do with security leaks that were discovered and fixed in the last couple of years.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to psql. The person who gave me the file expected me to use it. What can I do to import it nevertheless? Is the type in the public schema of database postgres?

Comment: You cannot import that dump. The person that created it messed up.